# phpMyAdmin returns blank/white page

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, apache2

[My phpMyAdmin page](https://escde.eu/phpmyadmin/) returns a blank/white page after I changed the MySQL root password [using this suggestion](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset). I also restarted Apache2 and MySQL using `service apache2 restart` and `service mysql restart`.

I've already tried a reconfiguration using `dpkg-reconfigure`. Far as I know it was working before, I am sure that there should be no extension missing.

It's pretty weird as `/var/log/apache2/error.log` gets no additional output. Even more weird is the fact, that [my phpMyAdmin page](https://escde.eu/phpmyadmin/) returns a blank page **but** some code (when you click `Inspect Element`).

Comment: What does the error log show? If you go back to your original password does it work again? That status code of the page is a 500?

Comment: The error code shows nothing. I dont know the status code of the page actually. @chris85

Answer (score 0):

You must to enable extension=php_mbstring.dll in php.ini.

Comment: I've added `extension=php_mbstring.dll` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658561/how-to-enable-mbstring-from-php-ini) post. After restarting apache2 again nothing changed.

Comment: Maybe you miss something during the installation process. I suggest you to reinstall xampp

Comment: As I already stated in my question - everything was working fine for months until I changed my MySQL-Password today.